# LDAP server - mobile application

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, ldap

I am working on a project for my university which is a mobile app for moodle ... we are doing it using phone gap my question is how can we do an authentication check against LDAP server. How can we retrieve information from LDAP in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default JNDI classes in Java are not very hard to understand. Basically:

1. Create an LdapContext object with the connection parameters for your server
2. Perform authentication
3. Query the LDAP server for data using the authenticated connection

Some sample code from my current project.

Step 1 and 2:
Create an authenticated connection using "userdn" and "password".

```
    private LdapContext getLdapContext( String userdn, String password )
{
    LdapContext ldapCtx = null;
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(5, 0.75F);
    env.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" );
    if ( ldapPort.equals( "636" ) )
    {
        env.put( Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
        env.put("java.naming.ldap.factory.socket", "portal.ldap.util.PortalSocketFactory");
    }
    env.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://"
            + ldapHost + ":"
            + ldapPort );
    env.put( Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple" );
    env.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userdn );
    env.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password );
    try {
        ldapCtx = new InitialLdapContext( env, null );
    } catch ( NamingException e ) {
        // Handle error
    }
    return ldapCtx;
}
```

Step 3:
Use the authenticated connection to read an object from the LDAP server.

```
    private Attributes getAttrs()
{
    LdapContext ctx = getLdapContext();
    try
    {
        return ctx.getAttributes( "cn=your,ou=object,o=dn" , { "cn", "yourattribute" } );
    }
    catch (NamingException e)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            ctx.close();
        } catch (NamingException e) {}
    }
}
```

The Attributes give you access to the data of the cn=your,ou=object,o=dn object. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The general approach is to use Java implementation the provides LDAP client functionality (e.g. [Unboundit](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/) LDAP SDK for Java), and develop a [plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) to expose the functionality inside the web view.